# Outlook AddIn `PropertyPage` not showing up in Outlook Options

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook 2007 Add-In project which I'm trying to add a PropertyPage to. I've implemented a `OptionsPage` class (which implements [`PropertyPage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.propertypage.aspx)) which is added during the `Application.OptionsPagesAdd` event.

```vb
Public Class OptionsPage
    Implements Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyPage

    Private Sub Me_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test Options Loaded")
    End Sub

    Public Sub Apply() Implements Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyPage.Apply
        ' todo
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Dirty As Boolean Implements Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyPage.Dirty
        Get
           ' todo
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub GetPageInfo(ByRef HelpFile As String, ByRef HelpContext As Integer) Implements Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyPage.GetPageInfo
        ' todo
    End Sub

End Class
```

```vb
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub Application_OptionsPagesAdd(pages As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyPages) Handles Application.OptionsPagesAdd
        pages.Add(New OptionsPage(), "Test Options")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Can anyone advise why I can't get the `OptionsPage` to show up within Outlook's Options, even though I don't get any errors or runtime exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need to ensure your class (that implements `PropertyPage`) has its `ComVisible` attribute to `True` in order for it to show up in Outlook - found [in this thread](http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=5&messageid=27276)

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(True)>
Public Class OptionsPage
    Implements Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyPage
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user control which implements the [PropertyPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.propertypage.aspx) interface. See [How to implement OL PropertyPage with c#](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=978) for more information.

Note, you can use [automatic language converters](http://converter.telerik.com) to get the VB.NET code if you don't understand C#.

Comment: My `OptionsPage` class is a `UserControl` and implements `PropertyPage`. I've checked the link and it doesn't offer anything additional to what I'm already doing. Any other suggestions?